# MATLAB still opens GUI after -nodesktop and -nosplash options

Tags: matlab, ubuntu

I want to open Matlab without the GUI, so pretty much just running it from the Linux terminal. For some reason adding the -nodesktop and -nosplash flags aren't working. Maybe there must be some sort of default settings, that are overwriting these flags? Is there any way to check this? Maybe I'm missing an extra flag?

```
$ matlab -nodesktop -nosplash
```

Other Details: Matlab 2012b, ran on Ubuntu 12.04.

Running:

```
$ matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -nojvm -nodisplay
```

doesn't work either.

Comment: try `matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nosplash -nodesktop`

Comment: Just tried it, same result unfortunately...

Comment: I'd expect that `matlab -nojvm` will do (probably an overkill) ... what Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: it seems like  Ubuntu 12.04 is not a supported operating system for MATLAB R2012a and above according to this thread: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB

Comment: Try out the options `-noawt` and `-noFigureWindows`.  They used to be undocumented methods of doing what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this as a workaround, it worked for me in a simple test (though I'm not running Ubuntu 12.04, so YMMV):

Before you call `matlab`, set the `DISPLAY` variable to a non-valid value. For instance:

```
export DISPLAY=:10.0
matlab
```

For me, this produces a terminal MATLAB session without a display or splash, even without the command-line options.

Answer (score 0):

Although you seem to have found a workaround, you may have luck with the following command line options:

```
matlab -noawt -noFigureWindows ...
```